# Joining seperate objects in armature?

Tags: mesh, rigging, parent

**Hey everyone!**
I'm new to Blender and finishing up my teddy bear model/rig - however, when I turn the head of the bear, the seperate nose layer turns and distorts differently to the mesh.

[image: Unmoved bear][image: Head rotated 90 degrees left]
(The bear front on, vs bear when the head is rotated 90 degrees left)

I've tried joining the objects (CTRL-J) to no avail. Perhaps it's to do with my hierarchy? Please let me know if you're able to help!

[**BLENDER FILE AVAILABLE HERE**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Xa2GZ7sMOT2U4RG0sT2nmYdyp_taSEJU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bad rigging of the nose, i.e. bones influencing the nose while they are not supposed to.

So what you need to do is select the whole mesh in *Edit* mode and remove the nose vertices from all groups, then assign them to the good vertex group which is "spine.006" (name of the head bone).

Now when you rotate the head you can see that the nose goes far away, but this time it's because the head is flattened, this is because the head is also bad rigged. So do the same things, and it will work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Moonboots! Fixed it beautifully for me, gonna go through and properly rig each piece to each bone to improve it. Originally rigged it with Mixamo which didn't work for me, hence the messy groups